# React Native PWA with react-native-view-pager

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, expo, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a React Native application with Expo, after a few weeks of development I wanted to check my app on the browser by running: `expo start --web`

The Expo project is starting without any issues, however when I navigate to the local address where the app is being served I get a nasty error:

[image]

This is my first React Native app and I'm not sure if the react-native-pager-view simply cannot be run in the browser or I just need to add some webpack configuration for it to succeed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

React native is not meant to work as PWA.
PWA is just a web application that depends on chrome features to look and feel as mobile app. But they are not such smoothly experience as with a react-native or android/ios app.
If you are trying to test this on the web, be sure that you are following the steps in the official docs of react native. And check the example app from react-native-pager-view that works, you could start from there